# How to avoid space between ion-header and ion-content on pull down in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic 2 to build an application. When I pull down the ion-content area, there is a gap or space between the header and ion-content. I am unable to find the solution to avoid it. Can any one help me to figure out the solution. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

add margin-top:-15px; style to list
 It worked for me